# HTML5 Video tag switcher for multiple resolutions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ffmpeg, paperclip

I have a Rails 4 app setup as a video upload/sharing site. I am using paperclip to upload videos and ffmpeg for processing 2 sizes of video into Mp4, ogg and webm.

I want to show the smaller 240p video to mobile devices. I can do that now with media queries or Bootstraps adaptive tags but I would prefer a "resolution switcher" button similar to what I see on various other sites showing "240, 480, 720, 1080" Is this possible to do automatically within the HTML5 video tag similar to the "CC Closed Captioning" button that appears when you add subtitle files?

I was trying to avoid using a custom player.

This was my quick bootstrap solution but would prefer a button/switcher.

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
    <video style="width:100%" autobuffer controls poster="<%= @video.attachment.url(:preview) %>"><source label="720" src="<%= @video.attachment.url(:original) %>" type="video/mp4" default><source label="ogg" src="<%= @video.attachment.url(:ogg) %>" type="video/ogg"><source label="webm" src="<%= @video.attachment.url(:webm) %>" type="video/webm"><track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="/assets/subtitles.vtt" default><p>Your Browser does not support the video tag.</p></video>
</div>
<div class="visible-xs">
    <video style="width:100%" autobuffer controls poster="<%= @video.attachment.url(:preview) %>"><source label="360" src="<%= @video.attachment.url(:mobile) %>" type="video/mp4" default><source label="ogg mobile" src="<%= @video.attachment.url(:oggmobile) %>" type="video/ogg"><source label="webm mobile" src="<%= @video.attachment.url(:webmmobile) %>" type="video/webm"><track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="/assets/subtitles.vtt" default><p>Your Browser does not support the video tag.</p></video>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you come up with a solution?

Comment: No I couldn't figure out a way to do it in the stock player without a custom player like videojs. Videojs works but I am still using this bootstrap solution because I couldn't get videojs to do multiple resolutions AND multiple fallback filetypes. Also cut it back to just mp4 and ogg versions because webm threw errors when processing files over 150mb and webm/ogg have almost the same browser compatibility anyway.